# On android in-app billing subscription, next payment(renew) date set with count of days? or date?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I want to know that

On in-app billing subscription, next payment(renew) date set with count of days? or date?

[example]

1. count of days / a monthly subscription product = 30days

   - start(first) date: 2019/3/31, next(renew) date: 2019/4/29
2. date / a monthly subscription product

   - start(first) date: 2019/3/31, next(renew) date: 2019/4/30
   - start(first) date: 2019/3/2, next(renew) date: 2019/4/2
3. count of days / a yearly subscription product = 365 days

   - start(first) date: 2020/2/29, next(renew) date: after 365 days
4. date / a yearly subscription product

   - start(first) date: 2020/2/29, next(renew) date: 2020/2/28?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions?hl=en

Comment: You can do all of there, if you want. See [this page in the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504).

Comment: Thanks! But there are only free trial time periods, they did not said count of days or date.

Comment: I've not got a Google Play account, but there must be some way to [set the subscription period](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails.html#getSubscriptionPeriod())  which accepts [ISO 8601 duration specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).